# How to avoid capitalised acronyms and abbreviations from being lowercased by .capitalize()? Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, capitalization

Capitalising the first letter of a sentence using `.capitalize()` works fine. Except when the first word of the sentence is an acronym like 'IBM' or 'SIM', which get lowercased (except for the first letter). For example:

```
L = ["IBM", "announced", "the", "acquisition."]
L = [L[0].capitalize()] + L[1:]
L = " ".join(L)
print(L)
```

gives:

```
"Ibm announced the acquisition."
```

But I would like this:

```
"IBM announced the acquisition."
```

Is there a way to avoid this - e.g. by skipping acronyms - while still outputting capitalised sentences like below?

```
"IBM's CEO announced the acquisition."
"The IBM acquisition was announced."
```

Comment: Do you have the list of acronyms?

Comment: Create a list of your acronyms and don't apply capitalize to them

Comment: No I not have the list of acronyms in advance. They could be anything.

Comment: Well if they could be *anything* then you've given yourself an impossible task...

Comment: Python is a programming language not an intelligent software or library to detect acronyms automatically.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Okay: so then basically I would have to write some rule stating that: if the first and second letter are capitals already, skip `.capitalize()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capitalize the first character of the first word:

```
L = ["IBM", "announced", "the", "acquisition."]
L[0] = L[0][0].upper() + L[0][1:] #Capitalizes first letter of first word
L = " ".join(L)

print(L)
>>>'IBM announced the acquisition.'
```